# cakephp: Call to a member function save() on a non-object and two table insertion

Tags: cakephp, orm, insert, relationship

I want to make an insertion at the same time.

Models:

Empresa:

```
 <?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

 class Empresa extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Empresa';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'UsuariosA' => array(
        'className' => 'Usuario',
        'foreignKey' => 'usuario_id'));

public $hasMany = array(
'IntegrantesA' => array(
    'className' => 'Integrante'),
'PlanificacionesA' => array(
    'className' => 'Planificacion'),
'MetodologiaEmpresasA' => array(
    'className' => 'MetodologiaEmpresa')
    );
 }
```

Usuario:

```
  <?php
  App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
  class Usuario extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Usuario';

public $hasMany = array(
'ForosA' => array(
    'className' => 'Foro'),
'DetalleSesiones' => array(
    'className' => 'Detallesesion'),
'UsuariorolesA' => array(
    'className' => 'Usuariorol'),
'TablalogsA' => array(
    'className' => 'Tablalog'),
'DocumentosA' => array(
    'className' => 'Documento'),
'DocentesA' => array(
    'className' => 'Docente'),
'EmpresasA' => array(
    'className' => 'Empresa')
    );
    }
```

View/Empresas/add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->create('Usuario', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('Usuario.id', (array('label' => 'Nombre la empresa', 'type' => 'text', 'default' => 'lal')));
echo $this->Form->input('Usuario.password',  array('type' => 'password', 'label' => 'Password', 'default' => 'lal'));

echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.nombre_largo', (array('label' => 'Nombre Largo', 'type' => 'text', 'default' => 'lal')));
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.nombre_corto', (array('label' => 'Nombre Corto', 'type' => 'text', 'default' => 'lal')));
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.correo', array('type' => 'email', 'default' => 'lal@lal'));
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.docente', array('type' => 'tel', 'default' => '1'));
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.0.semestre', array('type' => 'tel', 'default' => '1'));
echo $this->Form->input('Empresa.o.gestion', array('type' => 'tel', 'default' => '2014'));
echo $this->Form->end('Registrar');
echo $this->Form->end('Cancelar');
```

One thing that kind of bothers me is that even if this view is in Empresas, it calls an action of Usuarios. Is that ok?

Then, Usuario and Empresa are supposed to have a one-one relationship. would it be okay this?:
Usuario Model: public $hasOne = 'Empresa';
Empresa Model: public $belonsTo = 'Usuario';
I couldn't make it work so that's why it has a one-many relationship. However as it is now I want to insert in Usuario and Empresa at the same time, of course I would have to insert in Usuario first.

UsuariosController

```
class UsuariosController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $uses = array('Empresa', 'Usuario');

    public function add(){

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->loadModel('Usuario');
        $this->Usuario->create();           

        $usuario = $this->Usuario->save($this->request->data);

        if (!empty($usuario)) {
        $this->loadModel('Empresa');
        $this->Empresa->create();

                 $this->request->data['Empresa']['usuario_id'] = $this->Usuario->id;

        $this->Usuario->Empresa->save($this->request->data);
                  }
           }
      }
}
```

I can insert in Usuario with no problem, but this error appears when I try to insert in usuario and empresa.

```
Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Controller\UsuariosController.php 
Line: 35
```

Also, I wanted to use this lines, so even if the usuario insertion would be ok but not the empresa insertion, then it wouldn't insert anything at all. But I'm confused as where would be the right place for them.

```
unset($this->Usuario->Empresa->validate['usuario_id']);
$usuario = $this->Usuario->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object ... Line: 35` The controller code isn't 35 lines long - which line does this error correspond to? Check the class of the objects you're referencing (e.g. `get_class($this->Usuario)`) - if the class is `AppModel` your model files are misnamed/not used.

Comment: what is your cakephp version?

Comment: cake version 2.4.6, and yeah it shows 35 line because there were lots of commented code above, the specific error line would be:  `this->Usuario->Empresa->save($this->request->data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Ususario` hasMany `EmpresasA` then you have to do

```
$this->Usuario->EmpresasA->create()
```

etc...

also you don't have to loadModel `Usuario` and `EmpresasA` because cake load them automatically when the correct relationships are set

Comment: Well, when I saw your answer the thing that caught my attention was that you wrote "EmpresasA" and I thought 'but my model's name is Empresa', so I changed the names of "UsuariosA" to "Usuarios" and "EmpresasA" to "Empresas" and everything worked. I thought that "classname => Empresa" was the only thing that mattered, I guess not. Would you mind explain why?

Comment: you nedd to specify classname when the name of the relationship is different from the model name. This is usefull when you have more than one relationship to the same model. But this is not your case so all you have to do in your Empresa model is `$belognsTo = array('Ususario');` and cake will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

> One thing that kind of bothers me is that even if this view is in
>   Empresas, it calls an action of Usuarios. Is that ok?

this is because in the code you put `echo $this->Form->create('Usuario', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'add'));` but if you want to call an action in Empresas, you should put `echo $this->Form->create('Empresa', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'add'));`

> Usuario and Empresa are supposed to have a one-one relationship.
>   would it be okay this?:

Yeah it is ok to do this

try the following code and if

```
class UsuariosController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $uses = array('Empresa', 'Usuario');

    public function add(){

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Usuario->create();           

        $this->Usuario->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
      }
}
```

If there is anything, tell me.

Hope it helps!